# Storing a Database Online to be Accessed by GUI in Java

Tags: java, database, user-interface, jdbc

I want to create a data management system which will be used via a GUI, by many users in different locations. I want to use client/server connections when a user logs into the GUI, and then whenever anything is added/updated, the database is updated accordingly. I am wondering *firstly*, if this architecture is logical and will work? And *secondly*, whether I need to store the database online, or if it can be stored locally and then accessed by people online using the GUI? The database is currently in `MS Access` however I can migrate to another program if it will make things easier.

I am doing the GUI in `Java` and will use `JDBC` to access the database.

Comment: Have a look at n-tier architecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture Effectively you'll have a presentation layer (the GUI) communicating with the business logic layer (where you write the queries to the database) which is what communicates with the Data tier. Try using a DAO for the DB communication so that you can add additional logic for different databases over time. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no 'best' option, but a good solution would be to develop some web services that channel traffic to and from the database, then have your GUI call those web services.


That way you can control access far more easily, as well as ensuring data integrity by having the web service perform validation and sanity checks.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you use mysql database your connection is something like this in java jdbc

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  // Setup the connection with the DB
  connect = DriverManager
      .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://remoteUri/database-name?"
          + "user=user&password=userpw");
```

Comment: and why specifically mySQL? And wouldn't you say that making the raw jdbc connection available over the internet is a tad of a security risk? Wouldn't it be much better to expose the data indirectly through for example a web service?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Firstly you have to create a database (I would recommend Oracle). Then in your GUI you can connect to the database and each button in your GUI will do certain SQL statements that will alter the data in the database.

A good website I found is : http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_and_databases.html